# Add consecutive numbering to list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have lists which look like:

```
[('A', 'B', 'C'), ('D', 'E', 'F'), ('G', 'H', 'I')]
```

and what I'm trying to get should look like:

```
[('1', 'A', 'B', 'C'), ('2', 'D', 'E', 'F'), ('3', 'G', 'H', 'I')]
```

Comment: You need to provide information on or code for what you have already attempted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use enumerate to pack them into 2-tuples, and then map them back into one tuple:

```
my_list = [('A', 'B', 'C'), ('D', 'E', 'F'), ('G', 'H', 'I')]
new_list = [(str(x[0]),)+x[1] for x in enumerate(my_list, start=1)]
```

First object in the enumerate will be:

```
(1, ('A', 'B', 'C'))
```

We turn the number into a 1-tuple, map it into a string and then add the original tuple to it.

EDIT: Some different methods with time added

```
my_list = [('A', 'B', 'C'), ('D', 'E', 'F'), ('G', 'H', 'I')]*1000

new_list = [(str(x[0]+1),)+x[1] for x in enumerate(my_list)]
## 1000 loops, best of 3: 815 µs per loop

new_list = [(str(x[0]),)+x[1] for x in enumerate(my_list, start=1)]
## 1000 loops, best of 3: 766 µs per loop, by schwobaseggl

new_list = map(lambda x:(str(x[0]),)+x[1],enumerate(my_list, start=1))
## 1000 loops, best of 3: 989 µs per loop

new_list = [(str(index),)+values for index, values in enumerate(my_list, start=1)]
## 1000 loops, best of 3: 669 µs per loop, by Donkey Kong
```

Comment: Thank you! Already used enumerate but is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Unlikely but I'll try some other ways and time it :)

Comment: @AD28 if you're very concerned about efficiency, it's worth examining whether - a) you need this to be a string and more importantly b) whether you actually really need an entire copy of the list with extra copies of information already inherent in the list. That's already quite inefficient and you may find you could avoid it altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension with unpacking.

```
In [1]: t = [('A', 'B', 'C'), ('D', 'E', 'F'), ('G', 'H', 'I')]

In [2]: [(str(i), *j) for i, j in enumerate(t, start=1)]
Out[2]: [('1', 'A', 'B', 'C'), ('2', 'D', 'E', 'F'), ('3', 'G', 'H', 'I')]
```

It's also quite fast.

```
In [3]: %timeit([(str(i), *j) for i, j in enumerate(t, start=1)])
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.91 µs per loop
```

This does not work in Python <3.5. This behavior was introduced in [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/).

Comment: This does not work in Python 3 either - you can't use a starred expression in a tuple literal.

Comment: @DonkeyKong It works in Python 3.5. That what I used to generate the *actual IPython output* shown above.

Comment: Apologies, I actually wasn't aware of that. I was super irritated because I thought you had wrote code as if it were actual output that didn't compile... oops. Nice answer ;)

Comment: @DonkeyKong Which version of Python did you try?

Comment: 3.4.3 - this behavior you have in your answer is from [PEP 0448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) for version 3.5. First time I've come across it to be honest.

Comment: @DonkeyKong Ah. I thought it was introduced earlier. Updating the answer to reference the PEP you mentioned. Thanks!